# Adapter of RecyclerView, not working as intended

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have 2 adapters, they are all most the exact same code, the only difference is one receives one type of object and the other, other object.

This is the one that I'm having problems

```
public class BuyHelpAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BuyHelpAdapter.MyViewHolder>
{
    private List<LastPrices> _list;
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView data, nome;
        public MyViewHolder(View view)
        {
            super(view);
            data = view.findViewById(R.id.ProdListRowCodBarras);
            nome = view.findViewById(R.id.ProdListRowNome);
        }
    }

    public BuyHelpAdapter(List<LastPrices> list)
    {
        this._list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.prod_list_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int pos)
    {
        LastPrices lastPrices = this._list.get(pos);
        holder.data.setText(lastPrices.getData());
        holder.nome.setText(lastPrices.getTerceiro());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return _list.size();
    }
}
```

I'm using the same way but when using this one the RecyclerView it will be filled but without any data.

Edit: This what I have inside the `onCreate` many of this is done in AsyncTaskRunner (use both adapter like this and the other adapter works at 100% like I mention)

```
_recyclerViewList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        _recyclerViewList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        _recyclerViewList.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        _recyclerViewList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

This part is inside of the AsyncTaskRunner

```
_recyclerViewList.removeAllViews();
_recyclerAdapter = new BuyHelpAdapter(_listLastPrices);
_recyclerViewList.setAdapter(_recyclerAdapter);
```

The xml here the information must go (use this one on both adatpers)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ProdListRowCodBarras"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ProdListRowNome"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ProdListRowCodBarras" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have double checked the `_listLastPrices` it as 3 objets (the RecyclerView its to be filled with the 3 objects) when running through the `MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder` and the `void onBindViewHolder` the information is there but in the end the recycleView as 3 items inside with no data at all (know this because it fill's the separator)

What is wrong here? The other adapter that just receives a different object works at 100% without any type of problems

Comment: You're 100% certain that `lastPrices.getData()` and `lastPrices.getTerceiro()` are not returning `null` or empty in `onBindViewHolder`? I know you mentioned that you saw that "the information was there", but I'm unsure whether you're referring to the `LastPrices` object itself, or the return values of those methods. The fact that an exact copy of this adapter works and the only change is the item type leads me to believe there is something wrong with `LastPrices`.

Comment: Why do you need `_recyclerViewList.removeAllViews();` ?

Comment: Running at debug again give me a sec and will check again

Comment: @pushasha yes the object as information inside it to fill the required information, the `getData() and getTerceiro` will return the information that is needed.
@B.M Since the recyclerView its used several times I just want to clean all the information that it does have or just by `setAdapter` it will be clean by it self?

Comment: Yes no need to `_recyclerViewList.removeAllViews();`  that's the problem i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextView width not correctly set. Plase try to replace for both textviews

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

This will solve the problem.

Comment: That is done also, I did not add because I would know that would not come from there, but will update the question just in case

Comment: Updated the question, as you could see I did that all rdy

Comment: did pick the part of the code where I wass all rdy doing that, put it just on the top of `setAdapter` didn't solved :/ rly don't understand whats wrong here

Comment: Will try it out, but isn't the `onPostExecute` in the uiThread all rdy ? Have that part of the code in the `onPostExecute`

Comment: Did try , no sucess ;/

Comment: Would you please try to set a background color for recyclerView and set another color for item text view and then knock me. is anything showing or not?

Comment: Okidoki give me a sec, but I have the separator and it shows 3 seperators inside the recyclerView (since its 3 objects with data)

Comment: I did add a square to the TextView and  give it a colour green, but doesn't show ... but I do use the same XML file for both adapters and on the other adapter works at 100% (it shows the information) and the only diference between them its the list, they have diferent objects

Comment: Ok was messing with the XML of the layout, did remove the match_constrains from the width of the TextView and put wrap_content and they show, but the stupid thing is, the same layout works on the other adapter with the match_constrains, rly don't understand the problem

Comment: That's the main cause. Finally, you understand the actual problem.

Comment: Hehe I did found the cause of the problem, what I don't understand is that the same XML is used on both adapters, on one works at 100% on the other is causing problems